# System.IO.IOException: 'Process can not access the file'

Tags: c#

I am new in C# programming language. I have been trying to develop a lessor sensor application. While exporting the output file  I am having trouble with (System.IO.IOException: file used by another process) Exception . I can't really find the problem.  I want to create a text file of current date and time on desktop. Here is my code:

```
            string dateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            dateAndTime = dateAndTime.Replace('/', '-');
            dateAndTime = dateAndTime.Replace(':', '-');

            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + dateAndTime + ".txt");
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                var myFile = File.Create(path);
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
                tw.WriteLine(txtDateTym.Text + " , " + txtKQ.Text);//Creating file on given path if file was not created
                myFile.Close();

            }
            else if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))

                {
                    tw.WriteLine(txtDateTym.Text + " , " + txtKQ.Text);//writing real time data to text file
                    tw.Close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should change your way you create the path:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), dateAndTime + ".txt");
```

You see there is a comma instead of a plus before `dateTime`.

Second, you should either use the Stream returned from `CreateFile` as input paramter for StreamWriter constructor:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(myFile);
```

or just leave out the `File.Create` and use the `myPath` as input for StreamWriter as you do it. StreamWriter will create the file itself.

If you use `myFile` twice to create the file (`CreateFile` and `StreamWriter`, the second call will be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path).Dispose();
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                     tw.WriteLine(txtDateTym.Text + " , " + txtKQ.Text);

                }

            }
```

h
    `File.Create(path)` returns a `FileStream` which is the handle for the file
when you try to create a `StreamWriter` the handle is already taken

you can also look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info